# PuLP: How to write a multi variable constraint?

Tags: python, math, linear-programming, pulp

I am trying to solve [this optimization problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW5Yh.jpg) in Python. I have written the following code using PuLP:

```
import pulp
D = range(0, 10)
F = range(0, 10)
x = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("x", (D), 0, 1, pulp.LpInteger)
y = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("y", (F, D), 0, 1, pulp.LpInteger)
model = pulp.LpProblem("Scheduling", pulp.LpMaximize)
model += pulp.lpSum(x[d] for d in D)
for f in F:
    model += pulp.lpSum(y[f][d] for d in D) == 1
for d in D:
    model += x[d]*pulp.lpSum(y[f][d] for f in F) == 0
model.solve()
```

The one-but-last line here returns: `TypeError: Non-constant expressions cannot be multiplied`. I understand it is returning this since it cannot solve non-linear optimization problems. Is it possible to formulate this problem as a proper linear problem, such that it can be solved using PuLP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always a good idea to start with a mathematical model. You have:

```
  min sum(d, x[d])
  sum(d,y[f,d]) = 1   ∀f
  x[d]*sum(f,y[f,d]) = 0 ∀d
  x[d],y[f,d] ∈ {0,1}
```

The last constraint is non-linear (it is quadratic). This can not be handled by PuLP. The constraint can be interpreted as:

```
  x[d] = 0 or sum(f,y[f,d]) = 0 ∀d
```

or

```
  x[d] = 1 ==> sum(f,y[f,d]) = 0 ∀d
```

This can be linearized as:

```
  sum(f,y[f,d]) <= (1-x[d])*M
```

where `M = |F|` (number of elements in `F`, i.e. `|F|=10`). You can check that:

```
 x[d]=0 => sum(f,y[f,d]) <= M (i.e. non-binding)
 x[d]=1 => sum(f,y[f,d]) <= 0 (i.e. zero)
```

So you need to replace your quadratic constraint with this linear one.

Note that this is not the only formulation. You could also linearize the individual terms `z[f,d]=x[d]*y[f,d]`. I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was kind of suspecting that it was possible to write this in a linear form, but I couldn't figure out how, even after staring at it for a full day.